# Ubuntu 20.04 on LSI 9207-8i makes RAID arrays crash

Tags: raid

I'm building a big-box-o-storage using a SuperMicro 3U Chassis and Mainboard running a Xeon E5-2640 v4 CPU, 64 GB RAM and a 16-slot SuperMicro/LSI SAS2 6Gbs backplane driven by a LSI 9207-8i HBA in IT mode.
I have 16 3TB disks in the chassis.

I can create a 16-disk ZFS pool without problems. When I put a heavy write-load on it, everything goes wrong. Say I copy a 50gig file to the ZFS pool to stress-test the pool. I watch the pool's status with zpool status every 3 seconds. Within 20 seconds after starting the file-copy, all 16 disks start showing massive write errors and in less than a minute, most disks are faulted (the red LED's in the drive-caddies even light up).

At first, I though there might be something wrong with the ZFS implementation in Ubuntu (don't want to hurt anyones feelings here) so I destroyed the ZFS pool, wiped all 16 disks and created the same 16 disk RAID6 array with Linux soft-raid (mdadm).
Started the same copy-test and the array fell to pieces again. Massive write errors on all the disks.

I had firmware 20.00.07.00 (the last incarnation of P20 that was released) on the card because the box ran TrueNAS 12 before and P20 is required for TrueNAS.
P20 does have a bad reputation though (VMware certified P19 as the highest version for vSAN 6.x for a good reason as vSAN would drop disks with P20) so, using sas2flash.efi, I wiped the controller and put P19 on it, hoping that would fix the problem.
It didn't.
Heavy writes still make both ZFS and Linux MD arrays crash completely with all 16 disks suffering from large amounts of write-errors within 1 minute. Disks go offline, are marked as faulty etc. etc.
After a reboot and doing a ZFS clear, all is good again and stays good when I don't put a big write-load on it.

I have a lot of experience with Linux MD and with ZFS and tried many many things. All with the same result. Firmware P20 or P19 makes no difference. I'm sticking with P19 though, just to be on the safe side.

The crazy thing is that this chassis ran xpenology (a hacked Synology DSM) and TrueNAS without any problems at all. Solid as a rock and great performance.
I then wiped all the disks, installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 but can't get the array to run stable.

I'm at a total loss. I had another LSi 9207-8i card lying around so I swapped the cards but the problem remains. I also swapped the cable between backplane and HBA. Nothing worked.

My gut-feeling says it must be a firmware/driver issue but I read many succes-stories about this card and FW combo.

Comment: How is the heat in the case during the large file copies? The 9207-8i has a history of getting rather warm when under stress ... 

Comment: Case is well ventilated and has a cage-fan blowing directly past the cards. Temperature of card and drives is not an issue. Never had issues under xpnology or TrueNAS as I wrote. Also, the problem manifests itself directly. Within seconds after a write to array task (copy large file), the first drives start showing write errors. After 30 seconds, many drives will have been marked "faulted" in zfs status. After a minute, most drives are gone. I already stop the copy at that point as it's pointless to go on.

Comment: When I use the "disk benchmark" feature in Gnome, the reads are solid and stable but writes swing between 120 MB/s and 15 MB/s and is very erratic. Maybe the drive's write-caches on the HDD's are disabled? How to check and turn on when needed? Now that I think of it, that would make writes slow, not cause massive amounts of write errors.

Comment: In desperation, I replaced the 9207-8i HBA with a LSI MegaRaid 2960-4i card I had lying around. Created 16 RAID-0 arrays (1 for each HDD) which resulted in 16 disks being presented to Ubuntu. Then created the same RaidZ2 filesystem as before with the same parameters.
The driver used is the "megaraid_sas" driver.
The result: performance and stability are great. No SCSI errors what so ever in /var/log/messages when hammering the array. Wrote almost a terrabyte worth of large files to the array and it did not buckle. No errors, consistent stable write performance.

Comment: As merely swapping the LSI 9207-8i HBA with the LSI MR2690-4i card completely solved the problem, proving the other hardware (cable, backplane, disks) was fine all along, I guess it's fair to say there is a major issue with the combo "LSI SAS2 16-port expander + 9207-8i HBA (both FW19 and FW20.07) + mpt3sas driver in Ubuntu 20.04 on my system.